# Is there any reliable, repeatable way to find a folder on MacOS?

Tags: finder

I have a folder full of Logic projects on my local drive. Finder offers no way to get to it. It's a constant frustration. I can get to iCloud, Downloads, Applications -- but not my own files on my own disk drive.

I understand that Apple has strict usability standards, and I respect that, but is there any way to work around them and conveniently access my own files only own computer, other than a keyboard shortcut that I'll forget and have to Google every time? (It doesn't work anyway -- the first time I tried, there was no folder named "Logic" in whatever unknowable scope it's searching in; the second time I told it to open "Logic", it opened Downloads. I can take a joke as well as the next guy, but sometimes I just want to get to my files).

Is it possible to create a link to a folder on the desktop, or something functionally similar? Something I can easily find when I want it, and click on it?

To clarify: I'm coming at this from a Windows/UNIX based expectation that all the folders are in a unified tree that's rooted somewhere, and you use one application (bash, DOS prompt, Windows Explorer, whatever) to navigate that whole tree: Some branches of the tree are on the local disk and "real", others are "virtual", but they all have a chain of parents starting at the same root.

But I'm starting to think I may need to learn a different way of thinking about this stuff in order to use MacOS.

The actual problem I have here is: I shared three Logic projects via iCloud with a pianist. We recorded many takes of his parts at his apartment. Then I needed to copy the projects from iCloud back to my local disk. "Open three projects in Logic and Save As for each one" is a very slow and awkward way to copy three files from one folder to another (or archive, or whatever a "single file" Logic project actually is).

Comment: By default, Logic saves things to <user>/Music/Logic, which you should be able to access easily enough in the Finder. But you can save the files anywhere. Where did you choose to save them? What is the filepath to this folder? Please clarify what you mean by "Finder offers no way to get to it." Once you've found the folder, you can of course create an alias to it on the Desktop. Though this becomes less efficient as you add more aliases.

Comment: I think a lot of this is because Apple no longer by default shows mounted disks on the desktop, so people have lost the immediate & obvious way to start looking down the file hierarchy & learning how it works.

Comment: @benwiggy It's not clear to me how "should be able to access easily enough in the Finder" is an answer to "There is no visible way to access this in the Finder".

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's why it's a comment. When you've answered some of my questions, I might be able to show you how to navigate to that folder.

Comment: Are you saying that you've saved these files "somewhere", but you have no idea where, and searching with Spotlight has not yielded results?

Comment: @Tetsujin Is there some non-immediate and/or non-obvious way to start looking down the file hierarchy? IIRC MacOS is now BSD, so I'd imagine everything's in the file system somewhere.

Comment: @benwiggy Logic Pro X creates a directory called Logic, which is the default save location. The Save As and Open dialogs go there by default. The "Recent" menu is useful as well. I've never heard of Spotlight in my life. Are you hinting that there's another search feature somewhere, which I should be able to access easily enough? In any case, it sounds like the answer to "How do I browse arbitrary folders in Finder" may be "That's not what Finder does, use another application". Is that roughly correct?

Comment: Apple used to, by default, show mounted drives directly on the desktop - people would immediately think to start there when drilling down through the hierarchy to find something. Now they don't & instead prefer to show you Recents & make you use Spotlight [the magnifying glass on the menu bar]… which is all a bit nanny state, imnsho. Some of this might be a bit basic, but you could do worse than a quick read of the 'macs for switchers' stuff at https://support.apple.com/HT204216

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13433?locale=en_US explains better about file save location for the app. If you're doubtful, open Logic, try to Save a new project and remember the location.
2. Replying to your: "whatever unknowable scope it's searching in", there are two places where it is written that "This Mac" is being searched. So see there to find the scope.

[image]

3. You can add the folder Logic(if and when you find it) to the sidebar by dragging the folder to the Favourites.
4. You can go to Finder Preferences and set the folder under General -> "New Finder window shows" as your folder Logic. But you'd have to open a new window for that, so remember that shortcut as per File Menu in Finder.

Comment: Thank you. Life's been crazy, but I'll be able to try some of these ideas tonight. I don't understand your #2 at all, however. Is there any way to search my folders on the local drive, and where was it searching instead? Might it have been searching iCloud?

Comment: I ringed the scope selector - basically 'everything' or 'just here'.

Comment: @Tetsujin one more :). Did you leave the numbers erroneous intentionally?

Comment: I did nothing more than put a circle around the relevant area on the image, didn't look at any other aspect.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to create a link to a folder on the desktop, or something functionally similar? Something I can easily find when I want it, and click on it?

Yes.  There are a couple of options.

1. **Desktop Folder**:  Find any folder that you'd like to have directly accessible on the Desktop.  Right-click the folder icon to open the pop-up menu.  Pick `Make Alias`.  Drag the Alias to the Desktop.  (You can also rename the Alias if you want).
2. **Sidebar Folder**:  Open a Finder window.  Make sure you have the sidebar displayed (if not, navigate to `View`->`Show Sidebar`).  Locate the folder you want to have directly accessible.  Drag the folder to the `Favorites` section of the Sidebar.  (To remove an item from the Favorites list you can just drag it off the Finder window and release.)

Answer (score 4):

By default, Logic saves projects to `<user>/Music/Logic`. (where `<user>` is the name of your user domain.)

In the Finder, you can navigate to that folder by:

1. open a new window (`Command N`). If that doesn't show your User Home,
   type `Command Shift H` (or `Go > Home` from the menubar).
2. You should then see the *Music* folder, which you can select, and then click on the *Logic* subfolder.

You should also be able to search for logic files with Spotlight. Click on the Magnifying Glass icon in the top right of the menubar (or use `Command Space`), and type in the name of one your files. Or try typing `kind:logic` to get your most recent files. Click on "Show All in Finder".

Using the Search field in a Finder window is exactly the same as using Spotlight, except that it may limit the scope to the current folder, or the entire computer, either of which may not be useful. So make sure you're at your Home folder first.

The Finder should not really be any different from Windows Explorer or any other Unix/Linux file navigator. You may prefer to use Column View or List View, which will show the hierarchy more clearly. You can also click on the filepath in the titlebar to reveal a drop-down list of the filepath.

In Finder Preferences, you can set what location appears for a new window. This can be your Home folder, or the root of the boot volume *('Macintosh HD')*, or the device itself *('Ed's MacBook Pro')*, under which, the drives and network folders will sit.

Apple's guide to using the Finder is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201732).

Logic should also be able to open the most recent projects directly by name from the `Open Recent` menu item.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try Go | Home when I get home to the Mac tonight.